# Unhandled Exception in C# , dnAnalytics class

Tags: c#, exception, math, matrix, unhandled-exception

What is the problem in the following code? I get an Unhandled Exception error, and I dont see "NOT A SQUARE MATRIX" output.

> Unhandled Exception:
>   dnAnalytics.LinearAlgebra.MatrixNotSquareException: Exception of type
>   'dnAnalytics.LinearAlgebra.MatrixNotSquareException' was thrown.at
>   dnAnalytics.LinearAlgebra.DenseMatrix.Inverse () [0x00000] in
>   :0

```
public static dnAnalytics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix calculateTransformation (dnAnalytics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix inputMatrix) {


        dnAnalytics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix transposeOfInput = new dnAnalytics.LinearAlgebra.DenseMatrix(inputMatrix);             
        transposeOfInput= inputMatrix.Transpose();          

        try 
        {
            dnAnalytics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix    intermediate = (inputMatrix*transposeOfInput).Inverse() ;
            return transposeOfInput*intermediate;
        }

        catch(dnAnalytics.LinearAlgebra.MatrixNotSquareException myEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NOT A SQUARE MATRIX" );  
            throw myEx;
        }
}
```

**SOLVED, overloaded function had a problem, not this one.**

Comment: :) is your matrix follows rules needed for multiplication.. seems like only a square matrix can be multiplied by your code... no of rows must be equal to no of columns

Comment: yes ofcourse, but I was wondering why this catch block does not run, what drives me insane is how come a A*Atranspose is not a square matrix. I thought it may be giving singular matrix exception

Comment: you catch block is re-throwing the exception... it must be running.. have you debugged it?

Comment: actually, its solved as I edited above. The problem was not this calculateTransform function, it was with the another one being overloaded and I totally forgot about it. Thanks anyway Shoaib.